# Display issue with diacritics for a phonetic alphabet

Tags: unicode, fonts

I need to write unicode characters and diacritics in a web page. They are part of a phonetic alphabet designed for romanist studies (the Bourciez Alphabet). My problem is a display issue, I believe: the character codes are all OK in unicode, but some diacritics are not displayed as expected. 
Most notably, the 'COMBINING DOUBLE BREVE BELOW' (U+035C) does not display as expected: it appears not under the 2 letters to which it is supposed to apply, but under the last of those letters and the next character (another letter, or a space).

Here for instance, the combining diacritic should be under the first 2 "a" characters, but it is displayed under the 2nd and 3rd "a"; yet you can see that the combination has been applied to the first 2 "a"s, because they are displayed in smaller size than the normal "a"s: 
[result of combining double breve below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNhnf.png)

I'm using fonts which have those characters (I tried Arial MS Unicode, Gentium, and Lucida Sans Unicode). They all have the same display issue.

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: For clarity we're talking about this: **xa͜ax**? This depends on the font used to display the text. With Cambria it displays as expected. It also renders as expected in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble reproducing the problem. Connecting two characters with the *breve diacritic* seems to be working for me. First I enter the first character of the pair, then the U+035C character, finally the second and it shows as follows.

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBzt8.png)